# Is it possible to create zaps on behalf my app's users autmatically, without user needing a Zapier account?

Tags: automation, zapier

I have Integrated my application with Zapier so that it can be used as a trigger when a user makes a change on their account dashboard.

I would like to setup an automated Instagram post to their business Instagram account when they make a certain change.

So my question is:

Is it possible set up zaps on behalf of my app's users? This Zap would essentially use my app's Zapier integration as a trigger, and a post to their Instagram as the action.

We want to have customers sign in to their Instagram account from our website, which we can have them do via Zapier, and once this is done, the Zap is setup automatically, without them having to make a Zapier account and setup the zap themselves. Would this be possible or am I better of going another route?

Using the Instagram graph API has been a dead end for me since their system is undergoing updates and documentation seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is to obtain their Instagram login credentials through a form on your webpage, save it and use them to authenticate Instagram for the "Post on Instagram" action on Zapier. You can create make a selenium bot to create the new Zaps on your own Zapier account, with each of your clients Instagram login credentials. With those zaps, you can now automate Instagram posts to their business account whenever they make whatever changes on their account dashboard. This approach  ensures that everything is set up correctly with using the Instagram graph API which is unworkable for anyone without a direct line of communication to Meta- it is a thing of the past, at least for the independent developer.

Comment: This is a *terrible* idea.  You should never request them, let alone *store them unhashed*. Users should never give their passwords to you.